# How to Handle Basic authentication on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, authentication, selenium

I am facing a problem in handling the basic authentication on IE9 (platfrom =WINDOWS 7). Can some one help me in solving the issue.

I have followed steps mentioned in this Blog.

http://aleetesting.blogspot.in/2011/10/selenium-webdriver-tips.html

can some one help me in fixing this.

Thanks 
Raghuram.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What kind of errors / logs are you getting?

Comment: If you followed all steps in the blog, I have bad news for you - nothing else to try. (As long as I know)

Comment: So there is no solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well, so just in case someone else needs it:

See this Microsoft article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489/EN-US
Scroll down to the "Fix it for me" section, download and run the provided file.

I had also tried manually editing the registry as they describe it, it was not enough on Windows 7 / IE9. Running the "Fix it for me" made it work though.